# Meteor Vagrant can curl localhost:3000 but windows cannot open localhost:3000 windows 8.1

Tags: meteor, vagrant, windows-8.1

Good morning,

Working on installing Meteor on windows using the following guide:https://gist.github.com/gabrielhpugliese/5855677

As pointed out on other posts its a little dated and I needed to install meteor separately, which I used this guide: [Unable to install meteorite on Ubuntu VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067674/unable-to-install-meteorite-on-ubuntu-vm)

Currently, my set up can do the following:

- files stay in sync between vagrant and windows
- localhost:3000/ is working on the server

What I still need help completing:

- when opening localhost:3000/ in my windows browser, I get the "This webpage is not available

I know that the vagrant VM is correctly serving the app because I opened a new instance of vagrant and curled the localhoust:3000/

[image: curl output from second vagrant instance]

I am actively working in django and node and can successfully run apps locally on :8000 and :8080, I tested the meteor app on those ports but still couldn't connect.  I also created a windows firewall port exception on 3000 but the results didn't change.

I know that there is a windows-preview currently out, but that is not working for me and I have an issue being tracked in gitHub.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that might be worth mentioning is it is somewhat possible to use Meteor on windows.

More details here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Preview-of-Meteor-on-Windows.

With your vagrant machine it sounds like there is a problem with port forwarding on your localhost machine to the VM's ports.

One possible simple way to get passed this is to get your Ubuntu machines IP address and simply load it up using `http://<ip address>:3000`.

I'm not sure why the port forwarding isn't working on your machine. In general the reason is provided when you run `vagrant up`, if there was an issue.

Comment: yea I am already tracking an issue running the meteor for windows which is why I am trying this method in the meanwhile.  I tried 127.0.0.1:3000 which resulted the same.  Like I said above, I can curl the server and prove that the server is correctly serving the files, it is something to do with windows and now being able to make the connection to the server.

Comment: @user1941773 The ip address of your ubuntu vm is not 127.0.0.1 thats your windows IP address (at least when you access it from chrome). Your Ubuntu VM is a seperate machine which is why you can curl it from within it. Your windows machine isn't forwarding the requests from its ip (something not 127.0.0.1) to something that is 127.0.0.1. Use ifconfig to find its ip and request that or find out why windows isn't forwarding requests to the Ubuntu VM which is given when you run `vagrant up`

Comment: alright sorry for the confusion, after I run ifconfig I get the following: `inet addr:10.0.2.15` when I try the url `http://10.0.2.15:3000` I get the same no response.  Also, the `vagrant up` command results are here [link] (https://docs.google.com/document/d/1sLhKlBmNnMAkFDrkOWSCuXdfL-w4kU6XRrndl8IDjkY/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: so I used the following as a guide [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22060893/port-forwarding-vagrant-on-windows) I realized that in my vagrant file I didn't have `auto_correct: true`.  When I updated the line to the following `config.vm.network :forwarded_port, guest: 3000, host: 3000, auto_correct: true' the `vagrant up` command outputted 3000 as one of the ports forwarded.